# Meta-analysis with studies reporting both positive and negative estimates

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm organizing a meta-analysis on performances with studies showing sometime positive and sometime negative estimates.

Sometime the result of the study is in a positive direction, with higher scores corresponding to better performance (e.g., number of tasks completed).
Sometime the result of the study is in a negative direction, with lower scores corresponding to better performance (e.g., time to completion of the task).

How can I put together both types of studies?
What kind of mathematical correction can I do?

I was thinking of estimating the effect size (in Hedges' g), then multiplying per -1 the positive-sided studies, so all studies will be in a negative direction.
Is this a valid approach?

Comment: what other data eg S.D ?

Comment: This seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using multiple measures for the outcome then I'm assuming that you will be using standardized mean difference. Therefore, you would multiple the mean effect sizes by -1 (not the measure of variance) for one group (either the ones that are better when more or the vice verse) to make them all in the same direction.